# Creating a simple camlp4 grammar extension

Tags: ocaml, camlp4

Given this type:

```
type 'a variable = { name: string; mutable value: 'a }
```

I'm trying to create a syntax extension that would accept this syntax:

```
var foo = true
```

...and convert it to:

```
let foo = { name = "foo"; value = true }
```

Here's my attempt:

```
open Camlp4.PreCast
open Syntax

type 'a variable = { name: string; mutable value: 'a } 

EXTEND Gram
  expr: LEVEL "top"
     [ [ "var"; v = a_LIDENT; "=";  e = expr -> 
         <:expr< let $lid:v$ = { name= $`str:v$ ; value = $e$ } in  $e$ >>
     ] ]
  ;
END
```

(I'm pretty sure it needs that $e$ at the end of the substitution as a way of saying "the rest", but it also looks kind of suspect given that we want the value field of the record to have the value of the expression on the right - initially I did not have the ending $e$ there and got the same error)

I try compiling with:

```
ocamlc -I +camlp4 camlp4lib.cma -pp camlp4orf -c pa_var.ml
```

Which results in:

```
File "pa_var.ml", line 10, characters 50-51:
While expanding quotation "expr" in a position of "expr":
  Parse error: "}" expected after [label_expr_list] (in [expr])

File "pa_var.ml", line 1, characters 0-1:
Error: Preprocessor error
```

I do not know know why it seems to want to have a "}" after the name field of the record.  (Otherwise, am I on the right track here?)

Comment: I could be wrong here but your expression after `<:expr<` doesn't appear to be complete.  Is that how it's supposed to be?  (you have `let blah = blah in <<the end>>`)

Comment: @JeffMercado - do you mean it should be: <:expr< let $lid:v$ = { name= $`str:v$ ; value = $e$ } in $e$ >> ?  (that gives the same error)

Comment: To be honest, I don't know what it is that could be causing the error, it just looked to me like that expression could be a major factor in the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is that you use `camlp4orf`, which uses standard syntax for the code, but revised syntax for the quotations, along with a field name `value`, which is a keyword in OCaml revised syntax. The simplest fix is to uses `camlp4oof` to use standard syntax everywhere, but you could also rename that field.

PS: I really don't think it is necessary to write a Camlp4 extension to do this. I would suggest living with the redundancy and using `let foo = var "foo" true` instead. That would simplify maintenance, interaction with other codebases, etc.

PPS: A couple more comments :

- you don't want to implement it that way; if you want to catch toplevel declaration phrases `let x = foo;;`, you must live in `struct_item`, not `expr`, and in `expr` you may want to catch local declarations of the form `var <lid> = <expr> in <expr>`.
- If you insist on using Camlp4, you should avoid grammar modification using `EXTEND`, as you are doing right now. Instead choose `let foo = VAR true` as your concrete syntax, and use the `Camlp4Filters` mechanism to transform this into what you want. This will be much more robust and simple to implement.

Comment: yes, this is mostly an experiment with Camlp4 extensions, not necessarily intended for serious use.  I tried changing to camlp4oof as you suggest and it does compile, but it does not work as expected (perhaps this is addressed by your first bullet point): in the toplevel I did:# #load "camlp4o.cma";;# #load "pa_var.cmo" ;;#var x = true;;   gives: Warning 26: unused variable x.
Error: Unbound record field label name

Comment: also like the suggestion to use Camlp4Filters - more somewhat incomplete documentation to read ;-)  Is this page relevant to what I want to do? http://brion.inria.fr/gallium/index.php/Reflective_OCaml

Comment: see `camlp4/Camlp4Filters/Camlp4ExceptionTracer.ml` for an example of filter.

Comment: I would advise strongly against camlp4oof - it has (at least in all released versions) subtle bugs with parsing. Learn revised syntax (quite easy) and use camlp4orf.

Comment: @ygrek - I thought I was using the revised syntax, but didn't realize that 'value' was a keyword in that syntax.